# Phonegap - Android - call/launch an app from another

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to launch one app from another using Phonegap?  We want to call a player app from a store app?

We also need the 2nd app to be able to return a variable to a script in the first app.

Cheers 
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but you'll probably end up needing to write a plugin to call an Android Intent. Many of the core PhoneGap API's like Camera use Intents.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android